# Proving equivalence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that the set $A=(0,1)$ is equivalent to the set $B=[1,\infty)$ ?

I know I need to find a bijection from $A$ to $B$, but I'm not sure how to do so and prove that the function is bijective.

Comment: Hint: $f(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: Hunh, are you sure $B$ is half-open and $A$ is open?

Answer (score 2):

If it were not for the boundary points, $x\mapsto 1/x$ would do the trick: It is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. Where top get $1$  from? Or alternatively, we would like to fist get from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1]$ and could then use $x\mapsto 1/x$  as bijection $(0,1]\to[1,\infty)$.
The trick is Hilbert's hotel. Consider
$$ g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{n-1}&\text{if $x=\frac 1n$, $n\in\mathbb N$}\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then $\frac12\mapsto 1$, $\frac13\mapsto \frac12$, etc., so that $(0,1)$ is indeed mapped bijectively to $(0,1]$. Com bine with reciprocal to solve the original problem. By the way, this method can be used to augment any infinite set by an arbitrarily large finite set.

Comment: what do you mean by "combine with the reciprocal to solve" ?